# DirectX11 Equivalent of OpenGL code

Tags: opengl, c++, directx, directx11, alpha-blending

I am currently porting parts of my engine over to D3D11 from OpenGL and was trying to figure out how I would accomplish the following blending functions in D3D11.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL);
```

I believe it should be something like this:

```
D3D11_BLEND_DESC blendDesc;
ZeroMemory(&blendDesc, sizeof(blendDesc));

D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC rtbd;
ZeroMemory(&rtbd, sizeof(rtbd));

rtbd.BlendEnable = true;
rtbd.SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
rtbd.DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;

rtbd.BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
rtbd.SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
rtbd.DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
rtbd.BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
rtbd.RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
blendDesc.AlphaToCoverageEnable = true;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0] = rtbd;

m_D3D->GetDevice()->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, &m_blendMode);
```

However this does not work. How can I achieve the same effect as in the first code snippet?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the blend state in the device context?

Comment: Yes, I set the blend state in the render method when it is used.  m_D3D->GetDeviceContext()->OMSetBlendState(m_blendMode, blendFactor, 0xffffffff);

Comment: Three suggestions: One read this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn166874.aspx) guide, make sure you have [debug enabled](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx), and check the result of every Direct3D function that returns an HRESULT for failure: ``hr = m_D3D->GetDevice()->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, &m_blendMode);`` if ( FAILED(hr) ) ...`

Answer (score 1):

This portion of your code is not technically blend state, but could be affecting the behavior here:

`glDepthMask(FALSE)
glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL)`

D3D11 does have corresponding state to this, and you can set it by creating and binding a ID3D11DepthStencilState object, in a similar way to what you're doing with the ID3D11BlendState.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476506(v=vs.85).aspx for details.

Essentially you'd be filling out an D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC descriptor to create that object, and given that descriptor 'desc':

- desc.DepthWriteMask maps to glDepthMask value
- desc.DepthEnable = true/false corresponds to glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)/glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) respectively
- desc.DepthFunc maps to glDepthFunc value
- only turn on stenciling and assign the rest of the fields if you're using stenciling.